# Ashampoo burning studio returns error "missing windows media components"

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to run Ashampoo burning studio v1.14.5 and i'm getting the following error: **"missing windows media components"**

Can anyone help me with this error?

PS I tried to run sfc /scannow, but no luck there

Answer (score 0):

You may be running the N version of Windows:

> The N and KN editions of Windows 10 include the same functionality as Windows 10, except for media-related technologies (Windows Media Player) and certain preinstalled media apps (Music, Video, Voice Recorder, and Skype). You must install other software from Microsoft or another company for this communication functionality and to play or create audio CDs, media files, and video DVDs, to stream music, and to take and store pictures. New features such as Cortana, Windows Hello, and PDF viewing in the new Edge browser rely on Windows Media files that are not present in these editions.
>
> Some websites and software, such as Windows Store apps or Microsoft Office, use Windows Media-related files that are not incorporated into these editions of Windows. Users can make these websites and software work correctly by installing the Media Feature Pack for N and KN editions of Windows 10.

You can [download and install Media Feature Pack separately](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3099229/media-feature-pack-for-windows-10-n-and-windows-10-kn-editions-novembe).

Comment: i've installed KB3099229, but still not working :(